# Seeking a gvSIG plugin to go from shp to kml to cityGML

Tags: shapefile, convert, gvsig, citygml

I'm looking for a gvSIG plugin to convert .shp to .kml and then to .cityGML.
I'm working with gvSIG + 3D extension and I have .shp format data but I need it in .cityGML format.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please edit your question (click in between "share" and "flag") to indicate where you've already looked. Also you may need to state why you need the intermediate .kml format.

Answer (score 1):

In gvSIG 2.2, the last version of gvSIG, you can export .shp to .kml

You can download gvSIG 2.2 and its manual from here: http://www.gvsig.com/en/products/gvsig-desktop/downloads

Best,
Alvaro Anguix

http://www.gvsig.com/en/community/mailing-lists